# WCF not returning full string of data

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, wcf

I am building an android application that uses ksoap2 to request data to be sent back to the mobile application. I am using the windows communication foundation as my service. However, I am not receiving the full JSON data from the database using this service. Here is my configuration settings in the WCF

```
 <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" sendTimeout="01:00:00">
      <readerQuotas
        maxArrayLength="20000000"
        maxBytesPerRead="20000000"
        maxDepth="32"
        maxNameTableCharCount="20000000"
        maxStringContentLength="20000000"
        />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:1985/wcfservice/Service1.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" 
            contract="MyWCFService.IService1" 
            name="basicHttp"/>
</client>
<services>
  <service name="MyWCFService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp" name="basicHttp" contract="MyWCFService.IService1"/>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The message I receive back is not the full JSON string of data. It actually ends with three trailing periods like so

```
"ParentGroup": 80
"ID": 25
"Item...
```

I have a near identical ASP.NET web service that also pulls the data from the database in the same fashion, and I am able to get the full JSON string of data in the ASP.NET web service. But not with WCF. What am I doing wrong...

Comment: Where do you see the trailing dots? To me it seems to be your display tool that's telling you it's too much data for it's small window.

Comment: Post part of android code & .net code for fetching data in android app & inserting data in .net database using web service.